# Xtragrid sorting appears not to be reliably removed

Tags: winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I have a DevExpress Xtragrid on Winforms that I'd like to keep in the same sort order even when cells are edited by the user. My problem is that even after all the sorts are cleared (by ctrl-clicking the column headers) sometimes the rows will still jump around as though sorting dynamically. I wonder if anyone has any clue as to why this might be happening.

Comment: I have discovered that CRTL-click on the row header does not always restore row ordering the same way that right click on column header, then Clear Sorting does, would like to know why.

Comment: CTRL-click removes the sort glyph but does not always immediately reorder the visible rows, the reordering can happen later causing the rows to jump around at inopportune times.

Comment: I have discovered that this difference in (remove sort) behavior occurs when I have a filter applied to another column.

Comment: Filed support ticket http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q373714